# django/python TEMPLATE_LOADER error for dajaxice

Tags: python, ajax, django, dajaxice

I want to use django / djanxice and have set it  up in setup.py, url.py, etc...

but when I run the server, error occurs.

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py:113: UserWarning: Your TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting includes 'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader', but your Python installation doesn't support that type of template loading. Consider removing that line from TEMPLATE_LOADERS.
  warnings.warn("Your TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting includes %r, but your Python installation doesn't support that type of template loading. Consider removing that line from TEMPLATE_LOADERS." % loader)
No handlers could be found for logger "dajaxice"
```

I googled, but couldn't find such error.

Anyone can help why python installation does not support this Templat_Loaders?

My python version is 2.7.3, using OS X v10.8

Comment: can you post your settings.py (the part you set up dajaxice) and urls.py here ?

Answer (score 2):

The `.egg` resource loader from `django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader` uses the [`pkg_resources`](http://packages.python.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html) module from the [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) package if available.  If `pkg_resources` is not available on your system you will get this exception.

setuptools is a separate installation from the Python interpreter.

You should install setuptools as per the instructions at [this link](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#cygwin-mac-os-x-linux-other).